# Why are Eclipse project files modified when excuting the "Update Maven Project" command?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I installed Eclipse 2019-06 on a new workstation and imported our team's maven project. When running the "Update Maven Project" command, for all subprojects, some of the project files are edited, whereas they are not on my current workstation (with one exception). My station runs Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0.

Is there a way to determine why these modifications occur on this station and not on others?

Is there a way to turn off these modifications so that our projects are unified?

The modifications are the following :

- In the ".classpath" file, the lines with *** at the beggining are added

```
       <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
              <attributes>
                     <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
                     <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                     <attribute name="test" value="true"/>***
              </attributes>
       </classpathentry>
       <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test->classes" path="src/test/resources">
              <attributes>
                     <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                     <attribute name="test" value="true"/>***
              </attributes>
       </classpathentry>
```

- In the ".project" file, the "RiderProjectBuilder" buildcommand is added as well as the "RiderProjectBuilder" natures

```
              <buildCommand>
                     <name>org.fusesource.ide.project.RiderProjectBuilder</name>
                     <arguments>
                     </arguments>
              </buildCommand>
       </buildSpec>
       <natures>
              <nature>org.fusesource.ide.project.RiderProjectNature</nature>
              <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
              <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
       </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

- In the ".settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs" file, all the following lines are added

```
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportPreviewFeatures=ignore
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled
```

The exception I mentionned earlier concerns the line "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning" which is also added on my workstation. It seems to be replicating an exception I configured for one subproject to all other subprojects, and it is also annoying.

Comment: It sure looks like whatever is adding the builder is culpable. Do you have something with the name fusesource installed as a plug-in or references in the pom?

Comment: I searched the workspace and found a few references, but none that stuck to me as responsible for this :
- A few instances in ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi" which look like perspective data.

- A few in ".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xml.core\system_catalog.xml", .xsd files

- a few in the org.jboss.tools.central plugin in the following files: "main.min.js", "jboss_buzz.xml", "valid_jboss_buzz.xml"

- Finally in temp files in ".metadata\.plugins\org.jboss.tools.foundation.core\ECF_REMOTE_CACHE"
wtp-runtime-type: org.fusesource.ide.fuseesb.runtime.60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12) [releases notes](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.12.php#mozTocId569479) on **Workspace compatibility**

> Downward workspace compatibility is not supported. A workspace created (or opened) by a product based on Eclipse 4.12 will be unusable with a product based on an earlier version of Eclipse.

While individual projects could still be usable across different versions the paragraph above states that backward compatibility is not supported, meaning issues like the one you describe are expected to happen.

To turn off any unwanted modification as much as possible it's suggested to exclude IDE specific project files from git repositories.
Another option could be to normalize the IDE version across teams, i.e. make all team members use the same version.

Comment: The problem was that this was causing compilation problems in the new IDE. But I finally figured out how to correct the problem and I tried using the new configuration in all old IDEs and there were no problems. I still find it weird that the same project didn't compile for a matter of workspace compatibility.